# Printing object values in Spring jsp

Tags: forms, spring, jsp, jstl

I have a spring 3 application with select list.

```
    <form:select path="objectlist" >             
        <c:forEach items="${objects}" var="objects">
            <form:option value="${objects}" label="${objects.description}" >
            </form:option>            
        </c:forEach> 
    </form:select>
```

There objects are queried from database. Path is Object class attribute.

I would like to print the description of an object user has chosen.

When I use `${form.objects}` - I get an object instance written, but when adding `.description` there, it is `null`. What I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you sure to name the var like the items? Better use <c:forEach items="${objects}" var="object">

Comment: My problem is printing the selected value in **another jsp.**

Comment: I do not think I understand what you mean. Could you rephrase the question and add more description and background details? What you want to achieve?

Comment: @mjgirl: what do you mean with "in another jsp"?

Comment: My goal is to show a page of all of user choises before actual sending of the form. That's why I need to print the description value of what he chose from the select list.

Answer (score 0):

In `<c:foreach>` tag you should specify the variable where it will temporary store **each array element**. For some reason you are using same name as an array and at some point the two variables collide with each other.

Try this:

```
    <c:forEach items="${objects}" var="object"> <%-- Notice there is no letter S at the end --%>
        <form:option value="${objects}" label="${object.description}" > <%-- Here too --%>
        </form:option>            
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Please notice my comment above.